# Java usando jasper Report: El documento no tiene paginas

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports

Verán estoy intentado generar un reporte general de mi tabla productos que esta almacenada en BD mysql, mi problema es que me el erro:

> El documento no tiene paginas

el código que estoy usando es este:

```
if (e.getSource()==btnMostrarRepo) {
        
        try {
            Conexion con= new Conexion();
            Connection conn= con.getConnection();
                
            JasperReport report = null;
            String path = "src\\modelo\\Reporte\\reporte_Principal.jasper";
                
            report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
                
            JasperPrint jp= JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, conn);
                
            JasperViewer view= new JasperViewer(jp, false);
                
            view.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                
            view.setVisible(true);
                
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
```

Y bueno pss el error que me aparece es este:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller).

> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

el jrxml es este: [Reporte_principal](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mh253P1LyjACNWLPdRqwV8yGMWkmUeIb/view?usp=share_link)

query del jrxml:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM productos]]>
</queryString>
```

consulta principal del jrxml:

```
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="32" uuid="fa7cec56-4ec1-48e6-a26e-7266a995d174">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="63" height="32" uuid="53576e9c-de32-43d4-8439-0189d7f95227">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="913cd28f-7ddb-449c-b015-e36da190ccf1"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idproductos}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="64" y="0" width="115" height="32" uuid="183fc078-b0ba-41bb-a560-6fcf0338246f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="f5e0bb1f-3446-4007-94d7-7646e2378a8f"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nombre_Prod}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="138" height="32" uuid="29f1af13-8305-4c56-b1ea-d25296aa9d9a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="7a49c405-bf50-4b11-adb1-21a3275e468d"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{stock}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="318" y="0" width="126" height="32" uuid="03239689-9acf-4b23-b6a3-bfc34c5ed499">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="3bb2ee76-ed9e-4f9a-92b6-6f4189d3a460"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{costo_Prod}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="444" y="0" width="120" height="32" uuid="6729a301-20a3-4172-a564-9efe81163d50">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="8e0dd5c0-b32a-4c4d-a787-f6fcda64646b"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format($F{fecha_Ing})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="564" y="0" width="140" height="32" uuid="9490481d-2975-4532-a424-78c141ee23de">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d4633d5d-6744-4971-8c05-2c2bc4569a55"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format($F{Fecha_Venc})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Actualización: actualice la libreria de log4j que estaba desactualizada y me salio este error al darle al boton:
ene 03, 2023 9:25:50 P. M. net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter  ADVERTENCIA: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.

Cabe aclarar que en el preview me funciona el reporte, pero al presionar el boton me sigue apareciendo el error

Alguna solución? Estoy usando el ide eclipse, el jasperreport 6.20, y realmente no tengo idea por que pasa

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta la consulta principal del reporte.

Comment: lo lamento, no entendí el comentario

Comment: Agrega el contenido del archivo JRXML.

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando las [librerías (dependencias)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.20.0) correctas para jasper-reports 6.20?

Comment: Bueno se que estoy usando la librería de Jasper report 6.20 pero no sé si las demás sean las correctas

Comment: @padaleiana okey, si tengo bien la libreria de jasper en la versión correcta que es el 6.20.0, cuando te refieres a la consulta sql del reporte query? y ya estoy añadiendo el archivo jrxml

Comment: @padaleiana we, estaba actualizando la libreria de log4j que estaba desactualida, y me ahora al dar el boton sigue diciendo lo que no tiene paginas pero ahora en la consola me sale esto: 
ene 03, 2023 9:25:50 P. M. net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter <init>
ADVERTENCIA: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.

Comment: Bueno, al menos hay un poquitito de avance. Pulsá en [edit] y colocá lo que mencionaste en tu comentario, ya que es información relevante para tu pregunta. Además, ojo a lo que dice el mensaje, es bastante específico de hecho: ¿revisaste si está bien tu conexión?

Comment: No coloques tu código como enlace de Drive, sino muestra un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_) de tu código _en la pregunta misma_. No coloques toooodo el código, solo lo realmente relevante. Ya te indicarán si es necesario algo más.

Comment: @padaleiana no se bien que es exactamente lo mas relevante......

Comment: @padaleiana y la conexión en teoria esta bien ya que yo puedo registrar, actualizar y eso...no entiendo por que dice eso

Comment: Depurá tu código y fijate si tu variable _conn_ no es nula luego de asignar un valor (en `con.getConnection();`). De ser nula, revisá si tu cadena de conexión tiene todos los datos (IP, puerto, base de datos...) ¿Podrías mostrar tu clase _Conexion_? (si tenés datos sensibles como contraseñas allí, no olvides _enmascararlos_.)

Comment: @padaleiana weeee, lo logre muchas gracias por tu ayuda, era el con.getConnection XD, si daba null y después de debugearlo supe por que, vuelvo y repito muchas gracias por tenerme paciencia

Comment: ¡Qué bueno que lo hayas resuelto! No olvides colocarlo como respuesta (en base a [answer]) y luego [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer). Así ayudarás a que tu pregunta no se relance una y otra vez al inicio, y a que otros que lleguen a tener el mismo problema sepan cómo solucionarlo, ya que los comentarios son efímeros.